# Specific example Pull-back equality in manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, pullback, co-tangent-space

I have to prove the next equality
$$
\psi^*\left(\frac{xdx+ydy+zdz}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right)=dt
$$
wher $\psi^*$ is the pull-back of
$$
\psi:S^2\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3-\{(0,0,0)\}, \
$$
$$
\psi((v_1,v_2,v_3),t)=e^t(v_1,v_2,v_3)
$$

Using the pullbacks properties, I have that
$$
[\psi^*\left(\frac{xdx+ydy+zdz}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right)](v_1,v_2,v_3,t)=
$$
$$
[(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\circ\psi)d(x\circ\psi)](v_1,v_2,v_3,t)+[(\frac{y}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\circ\psi)d(y\circ\psi)](v_1,v_2,v_3,t)+[(\frac{z}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\circ\psi)d(z\circ\psi)](v_1,v_2,v_3,t)=
$$
$$
dt+(v_1dv_1+v_2dv_2+v_3dv_3)
$$
Now I should show that if I apply what I have there to a tangent vector I have the same result as applying $dt$ to the same vector, but I don't see how to apply the covectors to the vectors. It might be helpful to use that $i^*(xdx+ydy+zdz)=0$ where $i:S^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is the canonical inclusion. However, I get that
$$
[i^*(xdx+ydy+zdz)](v_1,v_2,v_3)=v_1dv_1+v_2dv_2+v_3dv_3
$$
I don't know why that should be $0$, neither how to use it in the original problem.

Comment: Just to calibrate, you know that $t = \frac{1}{2}\log(x^2+y^2+z^2)$? The formalism of pullbacks often has a way of making easy calculations look difficult.

Comment: I know that once fixed a point in $\mathbb{R}^3-\{0\}$ then the value of $t$ is that. I mean, I know that $\psi^{-1}$ works like that, however I can only use that equality when working in $\mathbb{R}^3-\{0\}$, but not in $S^2\times\mathbb{R}$. Don't really know how to apply that equality. Yes, it happened to me before, calculations seemed hard but then once you make them correctly they aren't. My biggest problem is that I'm struggling in order to find some specific examples of how pullbacks work, I only find theorical explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of $v_1,v_2,v_3,t$ you can just use $x,y,z,t$, then it gives

$$
\frac{x}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\circ \psi =\frac{e^t x}{e^{2t}(x^2+y^2+z^2)}=e^{-t}\frac{x}{x^2+y^2+z^2}=e^{-t}x
$$

as $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ in $S^2$, and

$$
d(x\circ \psi )=d(e^tx)=e^tdx+xe^t dt=e^t(dx+xdt)
$$

Therefore

$$
\psi ^*\left(\frac{xdx+ydy+zdz}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right)=\frac{xdx+ydy+zdz}{x^2+y^2+z^2}+dt=xdx+ydy+zdz+dt
$$

So we only need to show that $xdx+ydy+zdz=0$ in $S^2$. However this follows from the fact that

$$
xdx+ydy+zdz=\frac1{2}d(x^2+y^2+z^2)=\frac12d(1)=0
$$

∎

Comment: I've made a really stupid error in the calculations! Thank you, I didn't know how to make that last step.